# Where can I find Paladin Danse after dismissing him to Boston Airport?

Tags: fallout-4

Light spoilers ahead, be advised.

I killed Kellogg in the main story and had the Brotherhood of Steel arrive in the Prydwen. Paladin Danse became a companion and I was tasked to wipe out a castle full of super mutants. Now I've dismissed Danse and I'm fairly certain I send him to Boston Airport. When I glance at the map, both the Airport and the ship have one person living there. Though when I look around, I can't find him. Anybody know where I can find him? Or what area, where to look for?

I'm on PC, though would like to avoid using commands, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

During my playthrough, when I sent Paladin Danse to Boston Airport he ended up behind a quest locked door that isn't opened until the beginning of the Brotherhood of Steel mission [Liberty Reprimed](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Liberty_Reprimed). Unless you're willing/able to use console commands, he can't be reacquired until you start the mission and the door opens.

Obviously, the preventative workaround is to never send him to Boston Airport - use the Prydwyn (or any other location, really), instead.

Comment: I've had enough playthroughs where Danse disappeared between Fort Strong and heading to the Sentinel Site that him getting locked behind a door that doesn't open until Liberty Prime sounds completely plausible.

Answer (score 3):

After dismissing someone to the Boston Airport, they won't be in the Prydwen or even in the BOS controlled area. Fast travel to the Airport, turn right, and go through the hole in the wall to the waiting area and They should be there.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't know either why he doesn't show up but if you need to get him back there is a companion recall mod you can download and if you want to use it and don't know how to work it go to a chemistry station go to utilities and there should be an item called summon paladin Danse that doesn't require any materials. But just in case you can check the food area on the prydwen(hope I spelled that right) if you don't want to use this mod. (Of course you can use this mod get him, send him to red rocket or somewhere else then uninstall the mod) but that's only a suggestion.